# Overwrite settings file in test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, app-config, settings.settings

I love using the Settings.settings tool in vs. I much prefer a type safe, named way to get the variables I set there. The biggest problem I have when moving over from the general appsettings/configurationManager is that I need my test project to overwrite those settings.

It seems to be that when I use the settings.settings file in the test project, it doesn't overwrite the settings.settings file in the main project. Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

Also I'm using a web project, which means i'm getting the settings from the web.config in the main project, but getting them from an app.config in the test. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the settings have to be explicitly saved, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is done via its `Save` method.

Comment: That would be for persisting changes when the user does something. I dont need to persist as much as change the values at all during runtime to a new settings.settings file's values.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, im sorry, i almost instantly figured out my own solution. If i set the settings file to public in the main project, i can set those values to the values i have in my test project in a assemblyinit. I want to leave this up just in case anyone else has a better way. But I should have spent a little bit more time researching. I apologize.